# pip install web3 giving error - The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: pip, python-3.10, web3py

I have already tried a lot from last 3 days not not getting this solved.

`pip install web3` was giving another error so for resolving that I have already installed Visual studio build tools.

I have installed `C++` build tools and now another error is showing `The system cannot find the file specified`.

I have created virtual environment also.

I have even reinstalled `VSCode`.

```
PS D:\Blockchain\web3_py_simple_storage> pip install web3
Collecting web3
  Using cached web3-5.29.1-py3-none-any.whl (500 kB)
Collecting aiohttp<4,>=3.7.4.post0
  Using cached aiohttp-3.8.1-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (555 kB)
Collecting hexbytes<1.0.0,>=0.1.0
  Using cached hexbytes-0.2.2-py3-none-any.whl (6.1 kB)
Collecting eth-utils<2.0.0,>=1.9.5
  Using cached eth_utils-1.10.0-py3-none-any.whl (24 kB)
Collecting jsonschema<5,>=3.2.0
  Using cached jsonschema-4.5.1-py3-none-any.whl (72 kB)
Collecting eth-abi<3.0.0,>=2.0.0b6
  Using cached eth_abi-2.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (27 kB)
Collecting websockets<10,>=9.1
  Using cached websockets-9.1.tar.gz (76 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting ipfshttpclient==0.8.0a2
  Using cached ipfshttpclient-0.8.0a2-py3-none-any.whl (82 kB)
Collecting eth-typing<3.0.0,>=2.0.0
  Using cached eth_typing-2.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (6.2 kB)
Collecting lru-dict<2.0.0,>=1.1.6
  Using cached lru-dict-1.1.7.tar.gz (10 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting protobuf<4,>=3.10.0
  Using cached protobuf-3.20.1-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (903 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: pywin32>=223 in c:\users\himanshu mishra\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages (from web3) (304)
Requirement already satisfied: requests<3.0.0,>=2.16.0 in c:\users\himanshu mishra\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages (from web3) (2.27.1)
Collecting eth-hash[pycryptodome]<1.0.0,>=0.2.0
  Using cached eth_hash-0.3.2-py3-none-any.whl (8.8 kB)
Collecting eth-account<0.6.0,>=0.5.7
  Using cached eth_account-0.5.7-py3-none-any.whl (101 kB)
Collecting multiaddr>=0.0.7
  Using cached multiaddr-0.0.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
Collecting async-timeout<5.0,>=4.0.0a3
  Using cached async_timeout-4.0.2-py3-none-any.whl (5.8 kB)
Collecting multidict<7.0,>=4.5
  Using cached multidict-6.0.2-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (27 kB)
Collecting frozenlist>=1.1.1
  Using cached frozenlist-1.3.0-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (33 kB)
Collecting aiosignal>=1.1.2
  Using cached aiosignal-1.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (8.2 kB)
Collecting yarl<2.0,>=1.0
  Using cached yarl-1.7.2-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (122 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer<3.0,>=2.0 in c:\users\himanshu mishra\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages (from aiohttp<4,>=3.7.4.post0->web3) (2.0.12)
Collecting attrs>=17.3.0
  Using cached attrs-21.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (60 kB)
Collecting parsimonious<0.9.0,>=0.8.0
  Using cached parsimonious-0.8.1.tar.gz (45 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting rlp<3,>=1.0.0
  Using cached rlp-2.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)
Collecting eth-keys<0.4.0,>=0.3.4
  Using cached eth_keys-0.3.4-py3-none-any.whl (21 kB)
Collecting bitarray<1.3.0,>=1.2.1
  Using cached bitarray-1.2.2.tar.gz (48 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting eth-keyfile<0.6.0,>=0.5.0
  Using cached eth_keyfile-0.5.1-py3-none-any.whl (8.3 kB)
Collecting eth-rlp<2,>=0.1.2
  Using cached eth_rlp-0.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (5.0 kB)
Collecting pycryptodome<4,>=3.6.6
  Using cached pycryptodome-3.14.1-cp35-abi3-win_amd64.whl (1.8 MB)
Collecting cytoolz<1.0.0,>=0.10.1
  Using cached cytoolz-0.11.2.tar.gz (481 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting pyrsistent!=0.17.0,!=0.17.1,!=0.17.2,>=0.14.0
  Using cached pyrsistent-0.18.1-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (61 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\himanshu mishra\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.16.0->web3) (1.26.9)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\himanshu mishra\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.16.0->web3) (2021.10.8)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in c:\users\himanshu mishra\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.16.0->web3) (3.3)
Collecting toolz>=0.8.0
  Using cached toolz-0.11.2-py3-none-any.whl (55 kB)
Collecting eth-rlp<2,>=0.1.2
  Using cached eth_rlp-0.2.1-py3-none-any.whl (5.0 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: netaddr in c:\users\himanshu mishra\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages (from multiaddr>=0.0.7->ipfshttpclient==0.8.0a2->web3) (0.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: varint in c:\users\himanshu mishra\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages (from multiaddr>=0.0.7->ipfshttpclient==0.8.0a2->web3) (1.0.2)
Collecting base58

  × Running setup.py install for lru-dict did not run successfully.  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [5 lines of output]
      running install
      running build
      running build_ext
      building 'lru' extension
      error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> lru-dict

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```